# SPRING JSP Form with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a question to ask. I am getting this error while trying to save a new property into the database. Column 'property_id' cannot be null. An exception happens when tryint to save features list into the database. For some reason there is not relation between the property that was inserted and features. Property_id does not exist inside the object PropertyFeature.

Here are my data:

```
table 'property':

id
name

table 'features'

id
title
property_id [not null]
```

Entity Property

```
 @Table(name = "property")
public class Property extends...{

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    private String name;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PropertyFeature> features;  


    public Property() {
    }


    public Property(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public Set<PropertyFeature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(Set<PropertyFeature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }   

}
```

Entity PropertyFeature

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "property_feature")
public class PropertyFeature extends ... {


    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Property property;

    public PropertyFeature() {

    }

    public PropertyFeature(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }   

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }   

    public Property getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(Property property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

SPRING CONTROLLER

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    PropertyServiceImpl propertyServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
    public String accountPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) {       


        Property property = propertyServiceImpl.load(12L);

        ArrayList<PropertyFeature> test = new ArrayList<PropertyFeature>();
        test.add(new PropertyFeature("Feature 1"));
        test.add(new PropertyFeature("Feature 2"));
        test.add(new PropertyFeature("Feature 3"));

        model.put("property", property);
        model.put("testList", test);

        return "/test";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test")
    public String accountPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Property property) {        

        propertyServiceImpl.update(property);       

        return "/test";
    }   

}
```

JSP FORM:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="property">

Name <form:input path="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
Features
<form:select multiple="true" path="features">
    <form:options items="${testList}" itemValue="title" itemLabel="title"/>
</form:select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test" />
```

Comment: can you provide exception what you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate needs a foreign key on property_feature to join back to the `ManyToOne` mapped property. You have not provided a column through the use of `@JoinColumn` therefore Hibernate has created one in your schema using its defaulting mechanism. This is described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) in section 2.2.5.3.1.4.

You have mapped Property as being non-optional, therefore Hibernate expects that you always set a `Property` on your `PropertyFeature` before saving. You have added the `PropertyFeature` into the list on Property but you have not set the `Property` on `PropertyFeature`.

I would suggest adding a method on to your property class as follows:

```
public void addFeature(PropertyFeature feature) {
  feature.setProperty(this);
  features.add(feature);
}
```

then in your controller you can write:

```
Property property = propertyServiceImpl.load(12L);
property.addFeature(new PropertyFeature("Feature 1"));
```

Comment: Thank you, however I thought I can manage everything with the JSP path="" . and do just one line to save everything propertyServiceImpl.update(property);

Comment: You mentioned I can use @JoinColumn annotation. Can u give me an example ? When I am adding one I get exception "must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key"

Comment: You can use @JoinColumns where you have multiple keys.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but the question is - can I use them and still have 2 tables property and property_feature ? Not 3 - property, property_feature and property_feature_assigned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see were the problem is. In order to make it the way I want I need a third table to connect property and feature. In this case I can specify

```
@JoinTable(name="property_features", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="property_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id")})
```

In this case hibernate creates 3rd table and I dont have to set object Property into evey PropertyFeature instance. This is nice but I dont like the third table in this case.

I guess I will update my Property entity method setFeatures to something like that

```
public void setFeatures(Set<PropertyFeature> features) {
        for(PropertyFeature pf : features)
            pf.setProperty(this);
        this.features = features;
    }
```

Tested, works as expected. Let me know guys if there is a better way to handle it with 2 tables only. Thanks